# Changing the Integrand

Tags: calculus

$ \int_{-3}^{6} f(x)dx = 5, \int_{-3}^{0} f(x)dx = 8, \int_{3}^{6} f(x)dx = 2 $

How would I figure out $\int_{3}^{0} (5f(x)-8)dx = 5$

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the conclusion is correct (I get $49$). First switch the bounds:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = -\int_b^af(x)dx=\int_b^a(-f(x))dx$$

So

$$\int_{3}^{0} (5f(x)-8)dx = \int_0^3(8-5f(x))dx$$

Also

$$\int_a^b(f(x)+g(x))dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^bg(x)dx$$

So
$$\int_0^3(8-5f(x))dx=\int_0^3 8dx-5\int_0^3f(x)dx=24-5\int_0^3f(x)dx$$

And also notice that:

$$\int_{-3}^6 f(x)dx=\int_{-3}^0 f(x)dx+\int_{0}^3 f(x)dx+\int_{3}^6 f(x)dx$$

so

$$\int_{0}^3 f(x)dx=\int_{-3}^6 f(x)dx-\int_{-3}^0 f(x)dx-\int_{3}^6 f(x)dx=5-8-2=-5$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: I'm confused with how you got 24-5 etc on the first line. Second line also confused me with how it simplifies to the first.

Comment: @OGK, I added the properties I used.

Comment: When I substitude all the values for the last expression then multiply by 5 and subtract by 8 my answer is (-5)*5-8 which does not seem to be the answer

Comment: @OGK, I also said I get 49. I don't think your conclusion is correct. Maybe there is some slip in the writing?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we have $\int_3^0=-\int_0^3=-(\int_{-3}^6-\int_{-3}^0-\int_3^6)=-(-\int_6^{-3}-\int_{-3}^0-\int_3^6)$

(See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Conventions)

Answer (score 0):

Given that $$\int_{-3}^{6} f(x)dx = 5$$
$$\implies \int_{-3}^{0} f(x)dx~+~\int_{0}^{3} f(x)dx ~+~\int_{3}^{6} f(x)dx = 5$$
$$\implies 8~+~\int_{0}^{3} f(x)dx ~+~2=5$$
$$\implies \int_{0}^{3} f(x)dx~=~-5$$
Now $$\int_{3}^{0} (5f(x)-8)dx = -\int_{0}^{3} (5f(x)-8)dx=-5~\int_{0}^{3} f(x)dx~+~8~\int_{0}^{3} ~dx$$
$$=(-5)\cdot(-5)+8\cdot 3=49$$

Look @OGK I got the value of $~\int_{3}^{0} (5f(x)-8)dx~$ is $~49~$. I think the given information is incorrect.

Comment: That was correct!

Comment: The process I was using to solve is also correct. But I am confused how the answer be $~5~$?